# Hyperlink color not changing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set colour of hyperlink to white in paragraph, but still it is not changing

```
<p style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); a {color: rgb(255, 255, 255)};"><
Open Now <a href="http:mylink">Apply now!</a></p>
```

Comment: This part is wrong: `a {color: rgb(255, 255, 255)};`

Comment: I'm not an expert on CSS, but I'm reasonably certain that won't work. Add a `style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" to the `<a>`

Comment: use color:#fff if you don't need the alpha channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use inline styles you should have it like this:

```html
<p style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: green;">
  Open Now <a href="http:mylink" style="background: black; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Apply now!</a>
</p>
```

Background color was added in the example for being able to see the hyperlinks.

**EDIT:**

Just to make it clear if it was not already you should avoid inline styles if possible. You should use [Style Sheets in HTML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html)

So the above example with a css file would be (style.css):

```
p {
  background: green;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

a {
  background: black;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Then include your css file in the `<head>` of your document like this assuming you would call your css file `style.css` and it would be located in your project root (same level as index.html) in a folder named "css":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Open Now <a href="http:mylink">Apply now!</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use inline css, then you have to apply the style to the anchor tag:

```
<a href="http:mylink" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">Apply now!</a>
```

It would be wiser to use a stylesheet however:

```
p {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

p > a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

I trust, that you are aware, that these are now global styles and you will add Ids and classes by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your are using this code:
With this code you can not effect to the hyper link it will effect only the paragraph content:

Apply now!

If you want to work with hyperlink so you should use:

Apply now!

for inline CSS and if you want to user hover effect too you you will have to use this code: save it as "index.php"
**html code:**

Apply now!

---

**CSS Code** Use as onpage CSS
a`color: rgb(255, 255, 255;)`

a:hover`color:#555;`

Answer (score 0):

use this below css and html,

```
<style>
  p, p>a{ color : rgb(255, 255, 255);}
</style>

<p>Open Now <a href="http:mylink">Apply now!</a></p>
```